# VMware Authentication Service missing

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, windows-services, windows-11

After updating to Vmware Workstation 16.2.0, I'm missing the VMware Authentication Service.

Error Message:

> VMware Workstation cannot connect to the virtual machine. Make sure
> you have rights to run the program, access all directories the program
> uses, and access all directories for temporary files.
>
> The VMware Authorization Service is not running.

Services:

[image]

Repairing with the installer does not work, any idea what I can do?

Comment: The service is called "VMware Authorization Service" and it's indeed missing. I would suggest uninstalling and re-installing VMware.

Comment: Download your VMware App again from VMware.com . Uninistall VMware completely. Restart. Install the new download.

Comment: @harrymc I've already tried that, it didn't help

Comment: Is it possible that your antivirus doesn't like it?